# How to add document in DocuSign

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I have following request to be sent to DocuSign API,

```
"emailSubject": 'DocuSign API - Signature Request on Document Call',
                    "documents": [{
                        "name": test.pdf,
                        "documentId": 1,
                    }]
```

What I dont understand is, where should the documents name be present and what about the documentId.

I got an error as follows:

```
{ errorCode: 'INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER',
  message: 'The request contained at least one invalid parameter. A document was defined without setting the \'name\' field.' }
Error calling webservice, status is:  400
```

I think it cannot find the pdf.

Comment: enclose pdf name in quotes as it is a string: `"name": "test.pdf",`

Comment: Hi i have enclosed as "test.pdf" but i'm getting another error fs.js:427
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);

Comment: is the file `test.pdf` in the same directory with the script you are running?

Comment: its inside the same directory for now but i want to implement /public/upload/test.pdf

Comment: you should not use absolute paths like `/public/upload/test.pdf` use a relative path: `path/to/node/script/public/upload/test.pdf`. The error from fs.js is telling you that it can not resolve the path, it does not exist

Comment: sorry this is very stupid of but i tried everything, abc/public/uploads/test.pdf this still gives same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60529/discussion-between-emil-condrea-and-jyoti).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fill in a correct path into `name` field:

```
"name": "path/to/existing/pdf/test.pdf",
```

Comment: That shouldn't be needed in this node. It's just looking for an alias. `"documents": [{ "name": "test.pdf", "documentId": 1 }]`. There was an extra comma and no quotes around the file name.

Comment: @AndrewWilson, if you check the comments you will see all discussion. The first thing that I suggested was to enclose the name into quotes. In javascript extra comma is allowed.`var a = {a:1,b:2,}` does not throw any error

Comment: I read the comments and his example listed above was not what he was using, which was causing the issue.

Comment: In his comments he has `"name": test.pdf` which is not what was happening, he was attempting to call a variable that failed and that was the issue. The origional question should be edited to add that information and the answer `"name": "path/to/existing/pdf/test.pdf"` is not valid.